# VB.net linking two autocomplete textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have two autocomplete textboxes. One is for customer name and the other is for customer code. 
I have set up the Autocomplete for the customer and customer code textboxes using this code:

**Customer AutoComplete**

```
Dim ds As DataSet = obtainCustomerData()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    CustName.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("name").ToString().ToUpper)

Next

CustomerNameTB.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
CustomerNameTB.AutoCompleteCustomSource = CustName
CustomerNameTB.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

**Customer Code Autocomplete**

```
Dim ds As DataSet = obtainCustomerCodeData()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    CustCode.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("code").ToString().ToUpper)

Next

CodeTB.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
CodeTB.AutoCompleteCustomSource = CustCode
CodeTB.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

Now I want the end user to begin typing in either textbox, however if they select a customer based on name I want it to bring through the code on the other text box and if they begin typing a code I would like it auto populating the name.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ComboBox` instead of `TextBox` it would be just some simple settings:

1. Add 2 combo box, one for `Code` and another for `Name`.
2. Set `DataSource` of both combo boxes to the same list.
3. Set `DisplayMember` of one to `Code` property and another to `Name` property.
4. Set `AutoCompleteSource` of both to `ListItems`.
5. Set `AutoCompleteMode` of both to `Suggest`.

This way, each `ComboBox` will act like an index for the list and when you select an item from one of them, the other one will select the same item. One shows `Code` and the other shows `Name`.